# Как отправить post запрос с изображением на php сервер с android?

Tags: php, java, android

У меня вот такая задача: пользователь выберет изображение из галереи, потом мое приложение отправит это изображение на сервер(php). На сервере изображение сохраняется. Прошу прощения за отсутствие конкретики, но я новичок.
Заранее спасибо)

Я добавил такой код:

```
   Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
   photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
   startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, 1);
```

И написал метод:

```
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent imageReturnedIntent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        }
    }
```

Как мне "положить" изображение, которое вернулось, в объект File

Comment: [OkHttp: Posting a File](https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Recipes#posting-a-file)

Comment: А его можно также использовать в android?

Comment: Да. Даже нужно.

Comment: У меня появилась проблема с получением изображения из галереи